# How to disable all power management in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via Terminal?

Tags: 18.04, power-management

How do I completely disable all power management settings in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (non-GUI)? 
I don't want the system to sleep/hibernate/disable wifi and so on.

Thanks

Comment: I believe all you have to type in to disable the power management is `xset -dpms` and then to enable it is `xset dpms`.

Comment: xset works on Ubuntu server (non-gui)?

Comment: It should, it is a command line utility.

Comment: Your mention of "wifi and so on" is putting me off: AIUI power management and "power saving" are different systems. If you want to turn off USB power saving (eg wifi problems) that's different to disabling hibernation, et al..

Comment: I mean all kind of power management and power saving options. USB power saving, WIFI power saving, Hibernation, Hard disk sleep and all of this.

Comment: The `dpms` is only the Display Power Management, my bad, you might want to disable it anyway.  Also, you probably want to see https://serverfault.com/questions/321499/how-to-disable-all-power-management-in-ubuntu-for-a-server-netbook for disabling all power management.

Comment: I think from 16.04 -> 18.04 many things changed. I am not sure if the 16.04 instructions apply to 18.04 that is why I am asking.

Comment: 18.04 still uses the systemctl so that part should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem with the laptop ALWAYS going to sleep, in that the screen goes blank/black and I must reboot to wake it up.

I tried ... all of these
Screen Going into SLEEP MODE,  or BLACK,  when NOT set to!

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

• and a way to make this permanent, you need a gsettings override file...
‣ Open a new empty document in gedit, (or another text editor) on your host system.

STILL keeps going automatically to sleep!

OK so try this ... APM (Automatic Power Management) is ON IN THE BIOS or at a lower base level.

a strange solution That for now is working, is to edit grub with the **APM=OFF** parameter.  To do this

Open the Grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add the apm=off to a line that will look like this:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off apm=off"

Yours may be slightly different but add it to whatever is between the "  " (quotes) a more typical is to put it after the standard "quiet splash'

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash (IN HERE)**"

and one must Update Grub, after saving this file, using terminal with the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and of course ... reboot

FEWWWW!